# Matlab Default Color Orders and Types

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I'm looking for a way, preferably a GUI, to change the default line colors, their orders, and the types globally.

I want to specify that the first line to be this color, this type, and this width; the second line to be that color, that type, and that width; and so on.

Maybe a uitable with the row names being the line number (the first, the second, etc.), the colors specified in the second column, the type in the third, and the width in the fourth.  Something like this.

What is a good approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not fully the customization you are looking for, but you can set the default *colors* and line *types* (--, -., an so on) using `DefaultAxesColorOrder` and `DefaultAxesLineStyleOrder`, respectively:

```
myColorOrder =  [    
    0         0.4470    0.7410   % rgb triplet
    0.8500    0.3250    0.0980
    0.9290    0.6940    0.1250
    0.4940    0.1840    0.5560
    0.4660    0.6740    0.1880
    0.3010    0.7450    0.9330
    0.6350    0.0780    0.1840]

set(groot,'DefaultAxesColorOrder',myColorOrder,...
      'DefaultAxesLineStyleOrder','-|--|:|-.')

Z = peaks;
x = 1:length(Z);
y = Z(4:7,:);
plot(x,y)
```

The rows in the 3-column matrix `myColorOrder` contain RGB triplets describing colors, and the row ordering of this matrix corresponds to line color order when setting `DefaultAxesColorOrder` property. The default line styles (set to `DefaultAxesLineStyleOrder` property) is a single string containing line styles separated by `|`.

Note that when setting several colors as well as line styles, plots will cycle as follows:

- For first line style: cycle through all colors
- Change to next line style: cycle through all colors
- ...

For details, see

- http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/set-default-line-styles.html

---

If you really want to customize, you'll probably need to write a plot wrapper to customize plot line specs in the "manual way", however performed cleverly by the wrapper. See e.g. [the code for `Arrow3` by Tom Davis](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14056-arrow3-version-5/content/arrow3.m):

> The current LineStyleOrder property will be used if LineStyle is
>   specified with '*'.  MATLAB cycles through the line styles defined by
>   the LineStyleOrder property only after using all colors defined by the
>   ColorOrder property.  If however, the global variable LineWidthOrder
>   is defined, and LineWidth is specified with '/', then each line will
>   be drawn with sequential color, linestyle, and linewidth.

Possibly you can make use of Tom Davis' approach and apply to Matlab line plots.